# GNUPlot TimeFmt Issue

Tags: time, gnuplot, datetime-format

So I'm pretty new to GnuPlot, and I can't seem to find out why I'm getting the error I am.

Here's a sample of my data.txt file in the format **(irrelevant id,name,time)** :

```
3|Harpos|2010-08-28 02:44:55
4|Harpos|2010-08-29 02:22:25
5|Harpos|2010-08-29 02:09:19
26|Harpos|2010-09-03 03:01:09
```

With the following configurations (the xrange is the ultimate bounds of my data):

```
set xdata time
set timefmt x "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["2010-08-28 02:44:55":"2010-12-19 16:46:55"]
set yrange [0:500]
```

What I'm trying to plot is this:

```
plot '/Users/kyleturner/Desktop/Harpos-placeholder.txt' using 0:3
```

As I'm trying to generate the # of occurrences (0 being the sequence # for each occurrence) in my data that happen at a specific time (over series of months).

*However, I keep getting the error:*

```
"Bad format character"
```

Am I executing the "using" command incorrectly?  Can someone steer me in the right direction?  Once I get this down I'll be able to run some extensive sqlite queries to start generating some visuals.

**Thank you for your help, please let me know if I missed any details.**

Comment: Any ideas?  I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing

```
set datafile separator "|"
```

Also, it seems you want to have the date on the x-axis, and so you probably want

```
plot '/Users/kyleturner/Desktop/Harpos-placeholder.txt' using 3:0
```

Your handling of the time format is fine.

Comment: Hey Tom,

Thanks for your help!  I had executed that line in a previous attempt, but must have thought it couldn't of been the case.  I am now getting results!